# How can i set JTable in JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jdialog

I have a JPanel where i need to open other window (JFrame, JDialog, JOptionPane) that has JTable on it. After manual filling of JTable need to get its data back to JFrame.

How can this be made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you have to implement a method in your JDialog, where JTable is located, like this (return Object[][] is just an example, you can return any type of Collection) :

```
public Object[][] showDialogWithTable() {
   //do some needed actions
   setVisible(true);

   //when user closes JDialog with a JTable collect data from the table
   Object[][] data = collectData();

   return data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a model class (one that extends AbstractTableModel for example). Your JPanel creates an instance of the model that is initially empty. You can pass the instance to the constructor of the other window (the one that extends JFrame, JDialog, ..) and pass it to the JTable from there.

The edits of the JTable are reflected in the model and your main window still has access to the data through the instance of the model.

Comment: Main problem is that i can't make window for 2nd JTable. 2nd JFrame doesn't work, because it's created in other thread, so main JFrame still working and don't wait for data.
And in case with JOptionPane - i just can't generate it with JTable

Answer (score 2):

The view in your `JFrame` that needs to see updates should add itself to your table's model as a [`TableModelListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/tablemodellistener.html). The `TableModelEvent` will identify what changed.